# Send struct, float and int over UDP sockets in C++

Tags: c++, serialization, struct, udp

I want to send/receive structs containing float and int variables in client/server socket programs written in C++.

Earlier, the code was written in C, so I was simply sending them as follows:

```
//structure definition
struct {
    float a;
    float b;
    float c;
    float d[2];

}myStruct_;

//code to send struct
int slen = sizeof(client_sock)

if(recvfrom(sockFD, &myStruct_, sizeof(myStruct_), 0 ,(struct sockaddr *)&client_sock, &slen)<0) {
            printf("Failure while receiving data %d" , WSAGetLastError());
            getchar();
            exit(1);
}
```

But now in C++, this is giving me this error message:

> error: cannot convert '(anonymous struct)*' to 'char *' for argument '2' to 'int recvfrom(SOCKET, char*, int, int, sockaddr*, int*)'

I tried to look for this error, and found out that I have to serialize the struct before sending, and later deserialize the same to get the exact structure. Could you suggest/or provide an example how to serialize and de-serialize it?

Comment: You can just cast it like this: (char *)&myStruct

Comment: if i cast it into (char *) then how do i get the original struct back at the receiver's end?

Comment: At the receiving end you cast the address of an identical `struct` to `char*` and copy the receive buffer into that.

Comment: @Galik will the same thing work for float and int variables?

Comment: It would help to give your struct a 'type' like say: `struct MyType {...}`, that way when you get it back on the other end, lets say it comes in as say  `char *p`. You can just cast it back and use it like this `((MyType *)p)->a`, which would refer to that first float

Comment: Then you can also can do this: `MyType *m = (MyType*)p;` so can use `m->a; m->d[0]` etc.

Comment: "will the same thing work for float and int variables?" Maybe. Gotchas [are endianness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) and the [size of an integer being different](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types) on different platforms and compiler toolkits.

Comment: The problem with *floats* is they are platform/architecture specific so if you are sending them to a different platform/architecture you might do better sending text rather than binary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you showed will work fine in C++ with a little tweaking.

In some platforms (like Linux), `recvfrom()` is defined as expecting a `void*` pointer to the memory buffer that it will fill in.  In other platforms (like Windows), `recvfrom()` expects a `char*` pointer instead.

To get rid of the error, simply type-cast the buffer pointer (just like you do with the 5th parameter, where you are passing a `sockaddr_in*` pointer where a `sockaddr*` pointer is expected):

```
recvfrom(sockFD, (char*)&myStruct_, sizeof(myStruct_), 0, (struct sockaddr *)&client_sock, &slen);
```

Do the same thing when sending a struct:

```
sendto(sockFD, (char*)&myStruct_, sizeof(myStruct_), 0, (struct sockaddr *)&server_sock, &slen);
```